# Flux should have any arbitrarily value but why it is not the case?

Tags: electric-fields

According to the definition given to me the electric flux is the no. Of field lines passing through a given surface . But **field Lines are not absolute**, we define them relatively . 
So I can put infinite no. Of field lines at surface and hence the flux would be infinity . But why it isn't ??
Similarly I can arbitrarily chose the no. Of field lines and so the flux ...
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition you have is not really a definition.  It is a heuristic way of gaining some insight into the meaning of flux.  As you point out, you can draw as many field lines as you like.   Field lines are a mental picture to aid in understanding.  The actual definition of flux makes no mention of field lines.  It is defined mathematically as the integral of *electric field* over a surface.

Comment: But why we need to find the electric field intensity over a surface ??

Comment: It is admittedly a bit abstract.  Electric flux is the quantity that comes into play in the integral formulation of Maxwell's equations.  It's not *needed*, but it's use provides a number of benefits including simplification of some problems, providing a window on some symmetries of nature, and providing insight into the logical framework of electrodynamics.   There is a differential form of Maxwell's equations that does not use flux.  One can also work directly with force laws, but that is very difficult, and theoretically unwieldy.